# Change xfce4-settings:appearance (dpi scaling) options via terminal

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, dpi

I want to set the dpi scaling in **xfce4-settings:appearance** via bash script, so that I can bind it to a key shortcut. In the official docs I can only find the method to change it via GUI. Is there a terminal command to set the dpi value?

Thanks for help!
Basti

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's what you look for

```
xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Xft/DPI -s 100
```

You can take a look at `man xfconf-query`

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!!

Comment: @SebastianHoelzl You are welcome. I recommend https://forum.xfce.org/index.php for questions specific to xfce.

Comment: If the property doesn't already exist, `xfconf-query -c xsettings -n -t int -p "/Xft/DPI" -s 96` will create it.